Having CORS Error due to preflight request
I have a build a MERN typescript app. It was running perfectly, the api was on cyclic and the client on vercel but due to the shut down of cyclic I need to find a new free host plateform for my api.
I have chosen render.com to host the api but I am facing a CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api' from origin 'client' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here was the CORS settings that were used between cyclic and vercel.
const corsOptions = {
  origin: origin,
  credentials: true,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  // preflightContinue: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  exposedHeaders: ["Content-Range", "X-Content-Range"],
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

All the endpoints start with "https://" and end whithout "/"
What could I improve ?
Already tried several attemps. And have been reading doc but no success.
